# Large Data Populating Delay in Autocomplete in spite of Caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, autocomplete, browser-cache

I am invoking autocomplete with this ajax request:

```
source: function (request, response) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: handlerUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: requestString + "=" + request.term,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.length == 0) {
                            data.push({
                                id: noResults,
                                label: noResults
                            });
                        }
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Autocomplete is caching data after requesting from server. Data is cached but when it is creating the suggestion menu, it's taking huge amount of time.
Suppose I have 4000 data and all these are cached in browser. I cross-checked it by Networking option in IE. `304` type of result is coming which means that data is cached but still, it is taking time for autocomplete to convert those raw data{id,value pair} to HTML List as suggestion menu. And it's really taking Huge time.

Any way to mitigate this problem? I mean to decrease this population-time of autocomplete to convert raw data to Suggestion menu.

**EDIT**:

I've attached break-points at 3 methods of autocomplete, `search`, `response` and `open`. In second time, when the data is cached, then it's taking almost no time to come to `response` method from `search` method. But it's stuck after that and goes to `open` method after very long pause.

Comment: You are still making requests. 304 responses mean that you made a request and the server sent you the "not-modified" response. You can implement expires to prevent requests at all. Still, I don't think caching is your problem. Can you inspect the requests? How many do you make per second? Are they stuck at waiting?

Comment: @Slytael I have examined them with insight. Actually request to the server is not a problem. Because it's not taking much time there. I've attached break-points at 3 methods of autocomplete, `search`, `response` and `open`. In second time, when the data is cached, then it's taking almost no time to come to `response` method from `search` method. But it's stuck after that and goes to `open` method after very long pause.